# Points of Intersection

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I was looking for some help on how you find points of intersection using trig functions? I know you need to set both equations equal to eachother but Im a bit stuck on the solving aspect of it.

$$-\cos x= \sqrt{3}\sin x$$

Would you add $\cos x$ on both sides to make it equal to zero?

Comment: Are you familiar with the tangent function or the cotangent?

Comment: Divide both sides by $\sqrt{3}cos(x)$ to get $\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so $tan(x)= -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Comment: why would it go from -1/sqrt3 to -sqrt3/3

Comment: @Sariti The two forms are equal. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt3$.